# CSS: On hover show and hide different div's at the same time?

Tags: css

Here is CSS example how to show hidden div (on hover):

```
<div class="showhim">HOVER ME<div class="showme">hai</div></div>
```

and

```
.showme{ 
display: none;
}
.showhim:hover .showme{
display : block;
}
```

Can I show one div and hide another one **at the same time** by using **only CSS**?
Here is example how to use JS for this purpose: http://jsfiddle.net/joshvito/GaZQ6/

Answer (score 102, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/MBLZx/

Here is the code

```css
 .showme{ 
   display: none;
 }
 .showhim:hover .showme{
   display : block;
 }
 .showhim:hover .ok{
   display : none;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="showhim">
     HOVER ME
     <div class="showme">hai</div>
     <div class="ok">ok</div>
</div>
```

Comment: transition:all .3s ease-in;

Comment: adding '+' between two classes worked for me.. `.showhim:hover + .showme`

Answer (score 16):

if the other div is sibling/child, or any combination of, of the parent yes

```css
    .showme{ 
        display: none;
    }
    .showhim:hover .showme{
        display : block;
    }
    .showhim:hover .hideme{
        display : none;
    }
    .showhim:hover ~ .hideme2{ 
        display:none;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="showhim">
        HOVER ME
        <div class="showme">hai</div> 
        <div class="hideme">bye</div>
    </div>
    <div class="hideme2">bye bye</div>
```

Comment: sibling does not work there

Comment: @O.k it does, whoever edited my original answer put it into a stack snippet which it wasn't originally formatted for (there was a comment that was making the css invalid). Try the snippet again.

Comment: Yes, it works now! So, moral of the story is that stack snippets are evil :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried somethig like this?

```
.showme{display: none;}
.showhim:hover .showme{display : block;}
.hideme{display:block;}
.showhim:hover .hideme{display:none;}

<div class="showhim">HOVER ME
  <div class="showme">hai</div>
  <div class="hideme">bye</div>
</div>
```

I dont know any reason why it shouldn't be possible.